# Prevent extra newline after heading in md to rst conversion

Tags: markdown, pandoc, restructuredtext, github-flavored-markdown

I have some markdown files that I want to convert to reStructuredText files. I have just started using Pandoc for this particular requirement. So far I am using the following simple command

```
> pandoc --from markdown --to rst --columns 80 --output foo.rst foo.md
```

Now in my markdown I have laid out the text, such that there is no new line after the headings, for example:

```
# Some heading
Some text that follows on the line immediately after the heading
```

The result from the mentioned command inserts an extra new-line though:

```
Some heading
============

Some text that follows after the heading *and* a new-line
```

If I'm correct in thinking that this added new-line is not a requirement for reStructuredText, is there some simple way that I can prevent Pandoc from inserting it?

Comment: Actually, leaving out the blank line is considered "bad form" and both Markdown and reStrcuturedText [linters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) would insist you include the blank line in each respective document.

Comment: @Waylan Ah, so it's my md that needs adjusting rather than the rst output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Waylan commented, having a new line after a heading is considered the best practice style for markdown and thus Pandoc's insertion of them was correct.